# Tesseract OCR Extracting text from image file using asp.net mvc but not structure way

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tesseract OCR Extracting text from image file using asp.net mvc in viewbag getting text like below after extracting from image file

```
 Name raj mobile 90000000 address 5-848-7 india
```

below is code for extract text from image file

```
   public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName));
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);
            string extractText = this.ExtractTextFromImage(filePath);
            ViewBag.Message = extractText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
        }

        return View();
    }

    private string ExtractTextFromImage(string filePath)
    {
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/") + Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "tessdata";
        using (TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(path, "eng", EngineMode.Default))
        {
            using (Pix pix = Pix.LoadFromFile(filePath))
            {
                using (Tesseract.Page page = engine.Process(pix))
                {
                    return page.GetText();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In below line OCR Extract Text assingning to viewbag

```
   ViewBag.Message = extractText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");
```

The text is like below assingning to view bag

```
   ViewBag.Message="Name raj mobile 90000000 address 5-848-7 india";
```

I am not getting how to achieve key value pair to return view bag text paragraph to send below three fields edit form for user to check and validate and save this data.

```
  Name : raj
  Mobile: 90000000
  address: 5-848-7 india
```

In real scenerio my image file looks like below

https://nanonets.com/blog/how-to-ocr-purchase-orders-for-automation/#digitising-purchase-orders

convert Paragraph data to real display data.